# Get the value of a checkbox as an empty object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of checked checkboxes as an empty object `(checked = {})` This is my code:

```
for (const l of i.options){
        const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        x.setAttribute("class", "checkboxClass");
        x.value = l;

        const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
        const t = document.createTextNode(l);
        y.appendChild(t);


        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.height = "5px";
        div.appendChild(x);
        div.appendChild(y);
        document.getElementById("checkbox").appendChild(div);

        window.data.appendChild(x);
        window.data.appendChild(y);
        window.data.appendChild(div);
      }

const checked = [];
    document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").forEach((item) => {
      checked.push(item.value);
    });
```

How can I change it from an `empty array ([])` to an `empty object({})`? If this is not possible,should I rewrite the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays contain values, but objects contain *properties*, which have a value but also a *name*. So if you want to use an object instead of an array, you need to also use the checkbox's name. For instance:

```
const checked = {};
document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").forEach((item) => {
  checked[item.name] = item.value;
});
```

**But**, for that to work, you'll need to give your checkboxes names, which they don't seem to have currently. I mean, you *could* use the index of the checkbox as a property name:

```
const checked = {};
document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").forEach((item, index) => {
  checked[index] = item.value;
});
```

...but at that point you're basically creating an array, just without the useful `length` property and array methods provided by `Array.prototype`.

Comment: I set the name of each checkbox like ` x.name = "Checkbox";` and changed it as you mentioned `const checked = {};
document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").forEach((item) => {
  checked[item.name] = item.value;
});` but it seems to be getting the value of one checkbox. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong since I am setting the name of each checkbox

Comment: @nikoletakoleva - The names of the checkboxes need to be  unique, you can't have two different properties on an object that have the same name.

Comment: Alright, I will try to do so. Thanks for the feedback :)